# Assign static /dev/ttyACM[0-9] static

Tags: tty, usb-device

I have a couple of USB radios (one ZigBee, one Z-wave) that are currently located at `/dev/ttyACM0` and `/dev/ttyACM1`, respectively.

When I reboot, they are randomly assigned, rendering my home automation systems non-functional (until I manually change the designations in the config files).

I've set up a few USB storage in `/etc/fstab` using their UUID, is there a way to do something similar for the USB radios? From a bit of googling, and looking through this forum, I found their unique identifier (`ls -la /dev/serial/by-id/`), but I'm not sure what to do with it.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Great thanks! I've gone the first route (the `/dev/serial/by-id/long_id` way), it seemed simplest, given my setup. I just had to add that in my docker-compose, and in one "master-file" that is references by all other files needing that info.
[@mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy), if you make it an answer, I'll accept it, it might be easier for other people googling through this page?

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer -- this Q is probably a duplicate, but I'm too lazy and quite inept at googling ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `/dev/serial/by-id/long-garbage` directly instead of `/dev/ttyACM0`; it's a symlink to the corresponding device.

You can also make your a symlink with your preferred name by adding a udev rule in one of the files inside `/etc/udev/rules.d`; eg.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ... other conditions ..., SYMLINK+="ttyZigBee"
```

for a `/dev/ttyZigBee` symlink. (notice the difference between `==` and `=`).

You can check with `udevadm info -a /dev/ttyACM0` what attributes you can match on.